# Runtime determination of files used in a makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to generate a make file in Linux that is fairly dynamic and will take get all the files from the /src directory of a certain type. Essentially the output of ls *.type I seem to be having difficulties in doing this. Below is what I currently have but it does not seem to work. Hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks!

```
JIL_B_TMPL            : sh = ls *.type
JIL_LIST        =       $(JIL_B_TMPL)
```

I will also add this is not for compiling a C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture the output of a shell command in a makefile, you can do:

```
JIL_B_TMPL := $(shell ls *.type)
JIL_LIST   := $(JIL_B_TMPL)
```

This is of course the same as writing:

```
JIL_LIST   := $(shell ls *.type)
```

This works with GNU make, but since you mention Linux, I suppose you're using that.

Answer (score 1):

Pat got the core of something that works, but in your case, you'll probably want something more like

```
JIL_LIST := $(wildcard *.type)
```

This gets rid of a call to an external program, which will be important if you decide in the future that you want to support Windows. Also, if you're using makepp, the wildcard function will also catch any .type files that can be built, regardless of whether or not they already have been.